# Solving a ForAll optimization problem in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, logic

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem in Mathematica:

```
Minimize[{y0 + y2 m2, ForAll[x, y0+y2 x^2 >= Boole[x>0]]}, {y0,y2}]
```

Unfortunately, it just throws it back at me when I type it in.

I feel like this should be within what Mathematica can solve, being mostly about second-degree polynomials and simple range checks.

Is there some way I might convince Mathematica of this? Perhaps some assumptions I can add?

Ideally, I would like to generalize the above to fourth-degree polynomials as well. I wonder if there are some documented limits on which optimization problems are within the scope of Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Resolve` command should be added in your code:

```
Minimize[{y0 + y2 *m2,Resolve[ForAll[x,y0 + y2 x^2 >= Boole[x> 0]], Reals]},{y0,y2}]
```

> $$\left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & \text{m2}=0\lor \text{m2}>0 \\
>  -\infty  & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> ,\left\{\text{y0}\to 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & \text{m2}=0\lor \text{m2}>0 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> ,\text{y2}\to 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & \text{m2}=0 \\
>  0 & \text{m2}>0 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right\}\right\} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!